# Parseplatform: Prevent save without giving the client information over the outcome

Tags: parse-platform

I want to have a BeforeSave trigger, in which I decide based on some other table if a specific object should be saved or not.

I know I just can `throw`, then the object will not be saved, but then the client gets an error message. I want the client not getting any definite information about the saving status.

Why I need this is, we are having an app where only user with their email addresses preregistered in our system should be able to register. In order to prevent anyone from getting knowledge of the email addresses of our preregistered users, I don't want to send any confirmation of success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to return an error, you could create a wrapper function that always returns success in cloud code.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("saveUserEmail", function(req)){
    var user = req.user,
        email = req.params.email
    user.set("email", email);
    user.save(null, {useMasterKey:true});
    return;
});
```

And from your client:
`Parse.Cloud.run("saveUserEmail", {email:"email@domain"});`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion did it similiar, I'm using user.signUp() in my cloud code, instead of save.